# Determine current console codepage

Tags: node.js, windows

Is there a way to detect the Windows console codepage programmatically from within a Node script, apart from running `chcp` and parsing its free-text localised output?

```
C:\>chcp
Página de códigos activa: 850
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **no**.

However, it's possible to create a package that implements the feature and as of April 2018 there's [chcp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chcp) in the NPM registry.

You can stop reading now, unless you're interested in the internals :)

---

The package includes a [native add-on](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) and a module that exports the corresponding Win32 API method to be used from JavaScript.

Recipe to create your own package:

1. Install dependencies from elevated prompt*:

   ```
   npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
   npm install --global node-gyp@latest
   ```

   <sup>(*) Elevated prompt may not be necessary for `node-gyp@latest` but I'm not an expert and that's what worked for me.</sup>
2. Create a file called `binding.gyp`:

   ```
   {
     "targets": [
       {
         "target_name": "addon",
         "sources": [ "chcp.cc" ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Create build files:

   ```
   node-gyp configure
   ```
4. Create a file with your module source code, e.g. `chcp.cc`:

   ```
   #include <node.h>
   #include <windows.h>

   using namespace v8;

   void GET(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
     Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
     Local<Number> chcp = Number::New(isolate, GetConsoleOutputCP());
     args.GetReturnValue().Set(chcp);
   }
   void init(Local<Object> exports) {
     NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "get", GET);
   }
   NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, init)
   ```

   <sub>Note: there is no trailing `;`</sub>
5. Compile:

   ```
   node-gyp build
   ```
6. Finally, `require()` the resulting `*.node` file (without extension, base name can be changed to your liking) in your JavaScript code:

   ```
   const chcp = require('./chcp')
   console.log(chcp.get());
   ```

The `.get()` method returns a `number` (e.g. `850`).

This information was gathered though a [support ticket](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1067).